# Why do "auto-comment" options sometimes not work for review?

Tags: support

I've noticed that when I go to the "Review" section to look at things such as new answers in the queue, I sometimes have different options than other times.

Just now I was looking at an answer under the "New answer to old question" queue. I had options for "skip" or "no action needed". But there WAS an action needed; it was a new question posted as an answer. I wanted to flag it for deletion, and leave the "from review" comment that lets the user know to use "Ask Question". But that option wasn't there.

I manually flagged it for deletion, but this doesn't automatically leave a comment. How do you leave the "auto-comments"; why is that option sometimes there and sometimes not?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would bet that the available review actions and the results of those actions depend on which review queue you're in. In particular, I suspect that that comment comes from the queue actions to validate a "not an answer" flag in the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: Maybe I should include this in the question; but are the review options a StackExchange-wide thing; or can they be set for just Board & Card Games? If the latter, I think this post could also be updated as a feature request to make "auto-comments" available on all review queues.

Comment: I believe it's the same across the whole network, with the exception of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, it's only available for answers on Low Quality Review Queue, and yes, it's the same on the whole network including SO. Some users use a userscript to easen the process: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/22581).